# why I need to select "exchange" manually in outlook 2019?

Tags: exchange, outlook

The OS is Windows 10 1809 that joined domain.

In the previous Outlook(office 2016), user logged in by ad account, Outlook can be autoconfiged by click next.

But, after upgrading to Outlook 2019, only email address can be auto filled, but user need to choose "Exchange" manually and input password again.

Exchange is 2016.

So, is this a wrong config in Exchange Auto discovery?

Comment: It could be increased  security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely being caused by changes in office 2016 to prioritise office 365 and requires a regkey to be added.

https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/36052099-stop-prioritising-o365-for-autodiscover

https://www.gothamweb.com/portal/index.php/knowledgebase/8/Outlook-bypasses-AutoDiscover-and-connects-directly-to-Office-365-mailbox.html?language=danish

Answer (score 0):

In my environment of Outlook 2016, I need to type in my password after choosing “Exchange” manually. As for the issue you described, you can configure Outlook to choose the type of account automatically.